# Is it possible for a chrome extension to detect if it is in the dropdown?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'd like to use the same HTML file for multiple purposes - a login panel in an iframe in the browser, as well as a login panel in the dropdown.

Is there a programmatic way to know if I am in the dropdown versus anywhere else?

I've looked through the window object and I can't find anything unique that indicates that I am in the dropdown.

I would prefer not to use a custom URL for the dropdown (query parameters or somethinig like that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean a popup from a `Page Action` or a `Browser Action` then you can get the `chrome.windows` object and read the `type` property.

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(window){
  //window.type is an enumerated string ["normal", "popup", "panel", "app"]
});
```

Comment: I just ran this in my popup, and I get "normal" for my HTML in my popup. This is an HTML file attached via chrome.browserAction.setPopup.

Comment: @MikeKaply hmm, can you try setting the popup via the default_popup property in the manifest file and see if it makes a difference? You could try calling `chrome.tabs.getCurrent`. It will be `undefined` if it is called from a popup.

Comment: Even if it's the default_popup, it's normal.

chrome.tabs.getCurrent is a nice trick, though. That worked.

Comment: @MikeKaply I have never used the `type` myself, I just thought this would be the one thing it was for. Well I am glad something worked.